# How to resolve 'Android SDK license file not found' error in UE 5.1 and UE 5.2 despite agreeing to license in Android project settings in the editor?

Tags: android, sdk, unreal-engine5

The problem is that when trying to package an Android project in Unreal Engine 5.1 or 5.2, an error message is displayed stating that the Android SDK license file cannot be found. The error message suggests to agree to the license in the Android project settings in the editor. However, even after clicking the 'Accept SDK Licenses' button in the settings, the button doesn't get grayed out, and the error message continues to appear. This prevents the successful packaging of the Android project.

A successful Android package.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to accept the licenses from the command line?

```
yes | sudo /your/path/to/sdkmanager --licenses
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have ANDROID_HOME at your Environment Variables, that refers to your sdk directory. Then it will be able to find licences folder and it will work.